# Independent observations, and might this require a repeated measures ANOVA?

Tags: independence

below is a text for an assignment i am working on. I am getting really confused thinking about wether the the observations are independent in this example, because all of the people work together and they are not prohibited from talking to each other about how their absenteeism was treated by their supervisor. It to me would seem likely that if a new absenteeism policy was instated and, e.g. your boss would come visit you all of a sudden you might tell your colleagues about it.

Also the because they measure pretest, posttest and follow-up it makes me somehow think it also might be a repeated measures ANOVA. But i think i'm confused on that matter.

The assignment text:

Ceramics factory "The Purple Pot" suffers from an alarmingly high level of sickness 
absenteeism. Management has decided to do something about it, but is divided about the 
strategy: a financial bonus for persons who are seldom sick, a quick visit at home by the 
supervisor, or simply show their supervisors opinion about being absent because of sickness? 
Management decides to hire an intern from our department of Social & Organizational 
Psychology, who decides to investigate the following (combinations of) interventions, 
described by a 3 x 2 factorial design.

Design 
The first factor, which we will call Policy, is about interventions that cost time and 
money. This factor has three levels, coupled to three roughly comparible departments (random assignment of persons to treatments is not possible here; this is a quasi-experiment).

1 = House-call. In this condition, every worker who is sick will be visited within two days by his/her supervisor, who will inquire extensively about that person's condition, and act accordingly.

2 = Bonus. In this condition workers with relatively low absenteeism (≤ 12 days in a year) receive a financial bonus. In order to keep workers motivated, it will be stated on the monthly pay-slip whether one is eligible for the bonus, and how many others are.

3 = Control. For this group nothing changes.

The second factor, Supervisor attitude, distinguishes two interventions that cost nothing
(except for a short training of the supervisors).

1 = Punishment. Here, the supervisor emphasizes to workers who have recently been ill, how costly sickness absenteeism is for the company, and how annoying sick workers are to 
him (unfortunately, at the Purple Pot all chiefs are men) personally, without stating any 
explicit sanction.

2 = Rewards. In this condition, the chief emphasizes toward workers who have not been sick for the last two weeks, how pleasant this is for the company and how much he himself 
appreciates it (without explicitly stating a reward).

Within each department half of the workers are randomly (and without them knowing so) 
assigned to the punishment condition, the other half to the reward condition. All interventions are applied for at least one year.

Subjects

At the start of the investigation there were 156 workers, but due to turnover, illness and death only 138 workers have valid scores on all three measuring moments. They are divided over the conditions as follows.

---

```
               House-call Bonus Control
```

---

```
Punishment         24      24     23 

Reward             22      23     21
```

---

We can see that the design is not perfectly balanced, but it almost is.

Dependent variables

The most important dependent variable, sickness absenteeism, is measured at three moments.

• Pretest. Number of sickness absenteeism days in the half year before the start of the 
interventions.
• Posttest. Number of sickness absenteeism days in the half year after the start of the 
interventions. 
• Follow-up. Number of sickness absenteeism days in the second half year after the start of the interventions.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an assignment, I'll just offer some hints.  You ask about two possible violations of independence: The fact that the workers work together and the fact that each worker is measured 3 times.  These are sensible worries.

But for data to be dependent, *some* of the subjects must be more related than others. In one of your two areas of concern, this is true. In the other, it is not. Can you see which is which?

If all of the data are equally related, you may have a problem with generalization, but not with dependence.

Comment: When you say that some of the subjects must be more related than others, you might be hinting that they weren't randomly assigned to groups when it comes to the second factor, rather they were assigned based on department (pre-existing groups). Can you also explain why the fact that each worker is measured 3 times is not of concern? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I did not say that the fact that each worker is measured three times is not of concern.

Comment: So basically, now i do not know if what i am thinking is right and i feel still left in the dark. The assignment title also says it is about a factorial (two-way) ANOVA, but i was wondering if it is indeed a two-way ANOVA or in fact a repeated measures one since they measure multiple times. I am guessing right now the awnser to that question is not as straightforward and you could argue for both? Could you please give me some more hints.